# Get the size of objects on S3 with a single API call

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a Java application that extracts compress quite a few objects on S3 through streaming. So to make it more efficient, the application does not download objects on the local disk and upload them again, but it streams the files in 5MB chunks and compress them on the fly. The challenge I am facing is in order to provide progress on this operation, I need to rely on the total size of all the objects and use a counter to see how much from the total size is handled as the source of calculating the progress.

The challenge I have been facing is in order to get the size of objects, I need to iterate through all the objects first and get the size one by one and calculate the total before starting the process. However, this is going to be too slow as there might be millions of objects which means millions of API calls. If I try to calculate the size before starting the compression, this calculation process will take more than the actual compression and it defeats the whole purpose. Therefore, I was wondering if there is any way I can pass the list of objects via a single API call and receive the total size. I know there is a way to add a prefix and get the prefix match for all the objects that match a prefix, but since objects may get stored with different prefixes, this approach will not work.

The following code snippet is how I can get the object size one by one:

```
public Long getObjectSize(AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client, String bucket, String key)
        throws IOException {
    return amazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(bucket, key).getContentLength();
}
```

NOTE: If I relied on the number of objects to calculate the progress, that wouldn't be accurate at all. Some objects are 2-3KB and some of them are quite big (1-2GB).

Answer (score 1):

You could use Stream API of java 8 to turn iterate and made the sum of the values or 
maybe with using AmazonCloudWatch api to help you getting the BucketSizeBytes metric.
So you need to listMetrics and use BucketSizeBytes to GetMetricData.

Here the link of documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/AmazonCloudWatch.html#listMetrics-com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.ListMetricsRequest-
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html

Here some examples of AmazonCloudWatch:
https://www.javatips.net/api/com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.metric
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchClient

**UPDATE:**

Like I told you in one of this comments, you also could use command line interface.
In this  case, you also use cloudwatch, but through aws cli and you receive a JSON response format.
In one of the links that I put has an example, follows here:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name BucketSizeBytes
--namespace AWS/S3 --start-time 2016-10-19T00:00:00Z --end-time 2016-10-20T00:00:00Z --statistics Average --unit Bytes --region us-west-2 --dimensions Name=BucketName,Value=ExampleBucket Name=StorageType,Value=StandardStorage --period 86400 --output json
```

This other link have more explanations:
http://cloudsqale.com/2018/10/08/s3-monitoring-step-1-bucket-size-and-number-of-objects/

In summary, it seems that using cloudwatch is the easiest way to avoid many calls with iterations.

Comment: Thanks. Using Stream API won't help much as it turned all of them into a separate call anyway. Isn't any other way than using CloudWatch? We are using CloudWatch for the purpose of monitoring and operations only. It doesn't feel to use it for the implementation of business logic as well.

Comment: I totally agree with you about the correct use of the APIs, however I didn't find a method or a resource in S3 Java API to get the buckets size without an iterate in all of them. I think the other way is by the comand line interface executing inside a Java method.

Comment: I see. Could you please share the command line that can be used for this matter?

Comment: @Alin I will put on answer format because show in a best format